# How to make DSL compatible w/ both VS2010 and 2012?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vsix, dsl-tools

I'm in charge of a DSL/VSVM VSIX extension at work and, since VS2012 just got released, I want to make it compatible with both.

The VSIX is already installable in both environments, but I get load errors. I haven't fully checked, but I assume it's due to different SDK versions.

Is it possible to make my codebase compatible with both Visual Studios, without having to fork it?

Comment: Why are you against forking it?

Comment: I'd rather not mantain two different codebases - if it's the only way, I'll do it, but I'd prefer having different references/build scripts

Comment: @hb. Did you find a solution?
I found only this post about a normal extension not Dsl: http://www.corvalius.com/blog/index.php/corvalius/targeting-an-extension-for-vs2010-and-vs2012-using-a-single-manifest/

Comment: Nope, not yet. I haven't given it much attention as it's not a complete requirement yet, but it will be in the next few months.